# Setup and communicate between multiple rails user profile/roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, devise

A marketplace allows users to buy and sell items. It construct of **User** model and **Item** model. Each has many attributes, and their association is:

**user.rb**
`has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user`

**item.rb**
`belongs_to :user, optional: true, counter_cache: true, inverse_of: :items`

Each user show view is alike a profile where it shows all selling items.

Now, I want to introduce 2 type of users. Single seller/buyer (sell and buy few items) and Business (sell bulk/buy small or bulk items).

I created 2 models.

**Client**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :client
```

**Business**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :business
```

**NOTE:** While Business and Client share few attributes, they have many different ones. That's why I created 2 models.

And **User**

```
has_one :client, dependent: :destroy
has_one :business, dependent: :destroy
```

Also **Item**

```
belongs_to :client, optional: true, counter_cache: true, inverse_of: :items
belongs_to :business, optional: true, counter_cache: true, inverse_of: :items
```

While I "feel" it is a good thing to have separate models, I "fell" it's complicated when it comes to item creations and each entity show view.

**Required flow**

When a user signin, it is redirect to `/roles/new` view and choose to create a Client, a Business or both roles/profiles.

After user have one or both roles, is able to create an item.

Before in `item_controller.rb` I would do

```
def new
  current_user.business.items.new
end
```

Now, I'm not sure. I want to differentiate between which role create an item!

```
  def new
    if current_user.client
      @item = current_user.client.items.new
    elsif current_user.business
      @item = current_user.business.items.new
    else
      current_user.items.new
    end
  end
```

Does it make sense???!!!

Is the user a Client, Business or both. This is needed to show client's items in its' show view, same goes to Business.

While most likely User with either Business or Client role would not create the other role but it could happen. A user have both Business and Client roles.

A user with one or more roles should create an item, this item belongs to the role/profile that created.

I think of it like, an application has **Developer** and **Employer** profiles. Both belongs to **User** model and both could create/has many **Project**s.

Am I making the process complicated for myself or it is solvable?

Comment: I would consider if you want separate the concept of identity (eg authentication) from the buisness entities in the app and then have a one to many or many to many assocation between users and the "shops" (profiles) that they sell items though.

Comment: Instead of starting with the assocations I would use a peice of paper and draw up diagrams of the different buisness entities you need in your application and how they are linked together. Designing the overall structure of an app by coding usually doesn't yield good results. Start with the database design and how you're going to use the data and then build your code around it instead of vice versa.

Comment: @max I have done a digram for 4 tables, User, Business, Clients and Items. User has one client and one business, because user could have one or both. The Client and Business have many items. Items belong to User, Client and Business. User table is for authentication everyone signin and up to the marketplace. While Business(shops) and Client tables focuses on the business side.

Comment: @max To be honest, I'm not sure how to separate Client and Business tables from User. Each user "could" have one or both profiles. Would both inherit from User?

Comment: Not inherit. Make them separate buisness entities (eg tables) in thier own right that belong to a user (or even multiple users).

Comment: @max That's what I have now, 2 models belongs to user where user have one of each. What I'm finding difficult is creating an item that belong to Client or Business instead of user as I mentioned in Required fellow above. How would I go about doing that?